# Difference between "Übrigens" and "im Übrigen"

Tags: difference, meaning, colloquial

*Übrigens* and *im Übrigen* both mean *incidentally*/*by the way*. Are there any differences at all between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I want to say there are different "feelings" attached to them, but most of the people are not very sensitive about it. So using the one or the other it will never be very wrong.

> Übrigens schuldest du mir noch Geld.
>   Im Übrigen schuldest du mir noch Geld.

The first sentence is what you would throw in during a conversation because it just sprung to your mind: "No offense, but by the way, remember you owe me 5 Euros?"
The second has some slight undercurrent of accusation, like in "No, I can't help you out AND furthermore I want my money back" – or maybe also defense.

> Im Übrigen habe ich meine Argumente genau überprüft.

This nears *außerdem* or *darüber hinaus* – generally adding to a topic.
The "by the way"-statement is made with *übrigens*.

> Ach übrigens, gestern habe ich gelesen, dass die Milch teurer wird.

Comment: I'd say, "im Übrigen" generally means "furthermore/also"... not much need for nuance there.

Comment: Putting it so, I think you're quite right. Although I think it is difficult to answer only with the translation as I lack the feeling a native speaker of English would have (I was considering "moreover" first) and as I still maintain that used in a conversation noone will stop and muse about nuance but will only process some sort of "and" and focus on the information part of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

*Übrigens* is much more in use (although not just colloquial), *im Übrigen* is more formal.